# How can I save my Wordpress Site's current look, so I can revert back to an older version?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is customised and finished to my liking, but I need to change back to an older version of the site, using a different theme etc. Is it possible to save my current website's look as a draft through WordPress and not through backup?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a backup?

Comment: @idontwantnoscrubs I would prefer not to as the default to the older site look etc is only temporary, in the near future I would like to switch back very quickly.

Comment: the Duplicator plugin works very well. backs up all of the site files, posts, images, databases (etc) and then when you're ready to go back to the site you backed up you can simply run through the installer and you'll be back up and running. There's a step by step video on youtube that I normally use, but I'm at work and can't get on youtube, but just search for duplicator wordpress plugin. In my opinion this will be your easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to download the files from your server and save it some where.

[How to use FTP?](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-FTP) - check this

Also export your database, so you can re-use it later.

[How to export database?](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/export-database-using-phpmyadmin) - and check this